# Постоянное обновление метода

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста какой метод использовать для постоянной проверки, `update ()` я не обнаружил

Comment: обратите внимание на классы `Timer` и `TimerTask`

Comment: @RafaelOsipov можно немного по подробнее про них , буквально в 2ух словах

Comment: класс [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) и [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) используются для того, чтобы реализовать выполнение тех или иных действий по расписанию. Доп. информация: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/timer.php

Comment: Спасибо , обязательно прочту, вы можете указать это как ответ

Comment: Я написал ответ с моим примером использования этих классов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно выполнение некоторых действий по расписанию, то обратите внимание на стандартные классы [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) и [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

К примеру, у нас есть класс, в котором выполняется какая-то задача:

```
public class ProcessingUnit extends TimerTask {
    public ProcessingUnit() {
        // конструктор   
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
         // тут код
         // который надо вызывать по расписанию
    }
}
```

В нашем коде, где мы настраиваем таймер, делаем следующее:

```
ProcessingUnit processingUnit = new ProcessingUnit();
long interval = 60L * 1000L; // 1 минута = 60 000 миллисекунд
Timer processingUnitTimer = new Timer();
processingUnitTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(processingUnit, 0, interval);
```

Эта конструкция будет вызывать метод `run()` из объекта `processingUnit` каждую минуту, до тех пор, пока вы не вызовете `processingUnitTimer.cancel();`.

Я использовал [scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask, long, long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) По ссылкам на API стандартных классов, которые я дал выше, есть и другие методы, позволяющие настроить выполнение по расписанию.

UPDATE: если вам нужно выполнение повторяющихся задач именно для платформы Андроид, то обратите внимание на вот [этот пост](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android).